# On Win Startup - Open Browser Log Into Page, with Clicks

Tags: macros, automation

We have a display(only) screen that we will be adding in our hallway.  We need to allow the computer that will be running it to start up - Open a web browser - Enter credentials (specifically for this use), click login, click a few tabs in the page, etc., wait for 20 minutes (should a login timeout occur), then do it all over again.

Is there anything like this?  I have tried several macro recorders, but they did not work well as the site was taking longer to load the second time.

Please let me know if you have any ideas to make this happen.  I want to be able to set it and forget it.